# Why does homotopy behave well with respect to fibrations and homology with respect to cofibrations?

Tags: big-picture, homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology

(I apologize that this is a vague question).

I seems to me somehow that homotopy groups behave well with respect to (Serre)-fibrations. For example you get a long exact sequence of homotopy groups from it. On the other hand cofibrations and homotopy groups seems to be no good friends at all (e.g. $S^1\to D^2\to S^2$).

But then again, the situation in homology seems to be the other way round. They behave well with respect to cofibrations (you get a long exact sequence) and fibrations are harder to investigate (Serre spectral sequence etc.).

My question is: What is the intuition behind this difference? (in particular with respect to the fact that homology is just homotopy of another space.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I agree that the long exact sequence in homotopy groups of a fibration follows from the fact that fibrations are defined using a mapping property in which the fibration is the target.

One way to understand why homology behaves well with respect to cofibrations is to spell out your remark that
"homology is just homotopy of another space".  This is true, but not obvious.   There are a number of constructions of ordinary homology which take the following form.

One finds a functor $F$ from (pointed) spaces to (pointed) spaces which takes cofibrations to quasifibrations.   (A quasifibration is something for which you have a long exact sequence of homotopy groups, for example a Serre fibration).  And then $H_* (X) \cong \pi_* F(X).$  If $X\to Y \to Z$ is a cofibration (maybe a cofibration of CW complexes), then $\dots \to \pi_* F(X) \to \pi_* F(Y) \to \pi_* F(Z) \to \ldots$ is the long exact sequence in homology associated to the cofibration.

Here are several contexts in which one can describe such a functor $F$.

First, a formal approach.  Let $\mathbf{S}$ denote the category of spectra: it is connected to the category  $\mathbf{T}$ of spaces by adjoint functors $\Sigma^\infty: \mathbf{T} \to \mathbf{S}$ and $\Omega^\infty: \mathbf{S} \to \mathbf{T}.$  There a spectrum called the "Eilenberg-MacLane" spectrum, denoted $H\mathbb{Z}$: its job is to represent singular cohomology, and one can take $F(X) = \Omega^\infty ((\Sigma^\infty X) \wedge H\mathbb{Z})$.

Why does $F$ have the cofibration-to-quasifibration property?  Well, the way that this is set up, $\Sigma^\infty$ preserves cofibrations of CW complexes, and $\Omega^\infty$ preserves fibrations of fibrant objects, and in the category of spectra every cofibration is equivalent to a fibration.

To be more explicit about $H\mathbb{Z}$, you can define $F(X) = \lim (\ldots \Omega^k(X \wedge K(\mathbb{Z},k)) \to \Omega^{k+1} (X\wedge K(\mathbb{Z},k+1))a \ldots),$ where the limit is a colimit and the maps defining the system arise from the maps $K(\mathbb{Z},k) \simeq \Omega K(\mathbb{Z},k+1)$.

Second, the Dold-Thom theorem says that one can take $F(X) = Sp^\infty (X).$  Here $Sp^n(X) = X^n/\Sigma_n$, and $Sp^\infty(X) = \lim \ldots Sp^n(X) \to Sp^{n+1}(X) \ldots$, again the limit is a colimit.

Third, if you're willing to allow $X$ to be a simplicial set, then one can take then one can take $F(X) = \mathbb{Z}X$, the simplicial set whose $n$ simplices are the free abelian group on the $n$-simplices of $X$.  (This approach is due to Dan Kan; see the proceedings of the Hurewicz conference)

All of this is to focus attention on functors which take cofibrations to quasifibrations.  In fact all $-1$-connected generalized homology theories (at least the ones associated to cohomology theories: are there homology theories which are not?  I don't know) are of the form $E_* X = \pi_* G(X)$, where $G$ is a functor which takes cofibrations to quasifibrations.  Indeed one takes $G(X) = \Omega^\infty (\Sigma^\infty X \wedge R)$, where $R$ is the spectrum representing the cohomology theory.  This approach goes back to G. W. Whitehead.

One of the more compact discussions of such a functor, which I like, is in an article by G. Segal in Springer LNM 575; he gives a construction of connective real $K$-homology there.  Really he's showing how to generalize the work of Dold and Thom: Segal's argument applies just as well to $Sp^\infty(X)$.

I apologize that throughout I have done a poor job of saying how to handle basepoints.

Answer (score 12):

Fibrations are defined as target-type concepts -- they have good formal homotopy properties when you map *into* them, for example, if you apply the functor $\pi_n(-) = [S^n,-]$.

Now I'll subject you to my point of view on homology.

Dually, cofibrations are a domain-type concept, so they behave well when you map 
*out* of them, say if you apply (represented) cohomology:  $\widetilde H^n(-;G) = [-, K(G,n)]$.

Homology is a bit of a monster:  it is a covariant functor that works well with domain-type input.  It is a small miracle that such functors exist at all; this is why they are hard to construct.  But the answer for homology has to be:  homology works well with cofibrations because we built it to work well with cofibrations, and a more informative answer to your question would depend on the construction you use.

Comment: @Jeff: I don't get this: "Homology is a bit of a monster: it is a covariant functor that works well with domain-type input. It is a small miracle that such functors exist at all; this is why they are hard to construct." 

Comment: @John:  As far as I know, the exactness of homology (or its invariance with respect to suspension) depends on a substantial theorem (such as Blakers-Massey, or Freudenthal, or something else nontrivial).  There is no way that I know of to construct a functor that is covariant and exact on cofibrations without invoking a real theorem. 

Comment: What about the ordinary definition of singular homology?

Comment: @Eric:  Explain how you prove exactness, and I'll endeavor to point out the major theorem hiding in your proof.

Comment: @Jeff: point well taken. How about the following ad hoc construction: For $X\subset S^n$ a subpolyhedron, and fixed $n$ large, 
define $H_*(X) := H^{n-*-1}(S^n \setminus X)$.  It seems to me that this is satisfies excision: the point is that if $X= A \cup B$ then
$S^n \setminus X = (S^n \setminus A) \cap (S^n \setminus B)$ and cohomology as given by functions into an Eilenberg-Mac Lane space satisfies excision. 

Comment: You can prove exactness using just the fact that barycentric subdivision is a chain homotopy equivalence on singular chains (and the fact that sufficiently subdivided chains will always be subordinate to a given open cover), which is a very simple geometric fact about simplices and not something I would call a substantial theorem.  This is the proof in Hatcher (http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch2.pdf, p. 119-124).

Comment: @Eric:  Perhaps I should say (which is actually what I did in an earlier comment):  prove that it is a *homology theory* and there will be a substantial theorem.  You can push the hard work around, if you like, so I'm guessing that if exactness is easy, homotopy invariance is hard.

Comment: @John:  I am backpedalling *a little* as you can see in my response to Eric.  How do you prove that your homology is homotopy invariant?

Comment: Ordinary homotopy invariance is easy by a simplicial prism construction. If you mean weak homotopy invariance, that's more work but still pretty formal--the point is that given a weak equivalence $X\to Y$, any relative cycle in $H_*(Y,X)$ can be homotoped to $X$ relative to its boundary by obstruction theory.  Morally what's going on is that the map $|Sing(Y)|\to Y$ lifts to $X$ by obstruction theory (assuming $X\to Y$ is a fibration), and $|Sing(Y)|\to Y$ is a homology equivalence by the equivalence of singular and simplicial homology, but this only proves the map is surjective on homology.

Comment: Ordinary singular homology is built by forming the singular simplicial set, then turning it into a simplicial group and computing its homotopy groups.  This is essentially the simplicial set version of the infinite symmetric product construction, and the exactness follows from the fact that it turns cofibrations into some flavor of fibration.  

Comment: Sure.  My point is that there's nothing hard about showing it turns cofibrations into fibrations, or at least showing enough of that to get exactness.

Comment: I think we're going to have to agree to disagree here.  Maybe the problem is that we have different notions about what is hard, and maybe I wasn't being clear.  The point is, $[X, -]$ and $[-, Y]$ are exact for formal reasons:  that is, in any model category.  I don't think you can define $H_n(-)$ in any model category, so it's not formal:  its construction involves special features of the category of spaces.  

Comment: Eric, having spent an hour yesterday putting the proof of homotopy invariance on the blackboard in class, I'm going to agree with Jeff: it's a major pain!  Yes, there's a nice geometric idea about prisms, and Hatcher's rather loose notation makes it look a little simpler than it really is, but the details are messy and not at all formal.  For instance, how did Hatcher decide to break up the sums the way he did in his proof?  One has to get one's hands pretty dirty before coming away with a clean argument. There's hard work in there!  Same goes for barycentric subdivision of chains.  

Comment: I know this comment thread is long dead, and it's subjective to claim something is "easy" or "hard". But maybe this has to do with Jeff's opinions: $\pi_\bullet$ and $H^\bullet$ are (co)representable functors. Yet homology involves smashing with something, and smash product is surely a complex idea. Of course, passing to a spectrum-level discussion is already absurd in a conversation about "easiness", but it certainly shows you don't get the properties of homology "for free", the way you do for (co)representable functors.